# output the first letter of words in a sentence

Tags: c++, string

I was attempting to print the first letter of each words in a sentence in C++. My idea was to print the first letter of a string first , then print every letter after a space:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



string sentence;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cout << "Input your name!" << endl;
    cin >> sentence;

    //output first character
    cout << sentence[0] << endl;

    //output the rest of first characters in words
    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++){
        if (sentence[i] == ' ' && sentence[i+1]!= '\0'){
            cout << sentence[i+1]<< endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This solution only printed the very first letter of the string , and I was having trouble determining what went wrong with my code.

Comment: there is no '\0' in std::string.

Comment: trying to access `i+1` element will result a `out-of bounds` error if you use `.at()`

Comment: Thank you sudomakeinstall2 for your comment! I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::cin` will stop reading into a string after the first whitespace. So, if you input `hello world`, it will only read `"hello"` into your string. Instead, you can read an entire line into your string using `std::getline`:

```
cout << "Input your name!" << endl;
getline(cin, sentence);

...
```

Also, the contents of a `std::string` won't have a nul character (`'\0'`) in it whichever method you use, so your `sentence[i+1] != '\0'` check won't ever stop you from printing something.

Comment: Thank you Xymostech! it makes much more sense now :)